# MIN using SQL Language

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a question using the MIN function in SQL:

I have the question, List `pids`, `pnames`, and the minimum cost for that part among all the suppliers supplying the parts in descending order of the minimum cost. Hint: Use group by clause.

I have tables:

> Suppliers(sid: int, sname: VARCHAR(30), address: VARCHAR(50))
>
> Parts(pid: int, pname: VARCHAR(30), color: VARCHAR(10))
>
> Catalog(sid: int, pid: int, cost: double)

My current code looks like:

```
select distinct p.pid, p.pname, min(c.cost) from Parts p 
    left join catalog c on p.pid=c.pid 
    group by c.cost desc;
```

My result should only have each part printed out once, but in this case each part is printed out many times with many different costs. I am not sure if I am using the min function wrong, but how do I create this SQL query so that I can get the minimum cost of the part among all suppliers? Am I using the MIN function wrong or do I have a problem within the rest of my query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: You need to group by using pid and pname, as cost is your aggregated column, so it's not required in group by cluase

```
select p.pid, p.pname, min(c.cost) from Parts p 
    left join catalog c on p.pid=c.pid 
    group by p.pid, p.pname
```